# DatabaseMetaData interface does not work?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am trying the method of this interface explained here in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) tutorial:

Here I go:

```
DatabaseMetaData dm = con.getMetaData();
System.err.println(dm.supportsResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE));
```

I know it supports the `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` type. as I am using it and it works.
However the method above reported returns false. Have you ever tried using this method? If yes does it work properly? Thanks in advance.

PS: The same happens with the other 2 types of ResultSets (`TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`).
Considering that `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` is the default type it's a little bit strange that I get `false` in all three cases.
**UPDATE:** I am using JDBC-Mysql drivers;

Comment: Which JDBC driver and DBMS are you using? And just because you can request a ResultSet using `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` doesn't mean you actually get one.

Comment: `DatabaseMetaData` is an interface, the actual information provided depends on your driver implementation and if they correctly implemented `DatabaseMetaData`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in MySQL Connector/J 5.1.21 is:

```
public boolean supportsResultSetType(int type) throws SQLException {
    return (type == ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
}
```

However a quick look at the rest of the implementation suggests that MySQL also supports the other types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the Connector/J driver (there is more than one JDBC driver for MySQL), from the [MySQL Connector/J JDBC implementation notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html):

- "MySQL does not support SQL cursors, and the JDBC driver doesn't emulate them", and
- "By default, ResultSets are completely retrieved and stored in memory."

Since `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`, `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, and `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` usually indicate cursor types, then the statement that the driver doesn't even attempt to emulate them may explain why `supportsResultSetType(...)` returns FALSE for all values.  With the default behavior of holding the entire result set in memory, forward-only or scrolling modes would be irrelevant.